# Why doesn't this XML code color the background of the overflow menu in Android 4.3?

Tags: android, xml, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I am trying to color the popup menu (when clicking the overflow three vertical dots), but it doesn't work:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopupMenu</item>

        <!-- None of these work either -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/MyPopupMenu</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/MyPopupMenu</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Popup Menu Background Color styles -->

    <!--
        I also tried parent as:
              android:Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow
              @style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ListPopupWindow
              @android:style/Widget.Holo.ListPopupWindow
    -->
    <style name="MyPopupMenu"
    parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

And in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

Why is it still showing with the default black background?

Comment: does it work in other versions?

Comment: @waqaslam it also does not work with 4.4

Answer (score 1):

Make sure, yo have applied styles as per version based...

values.xml
    replace

```
<item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopupMenu</item>

to

<item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopupMenu</item>
```

values-14.xml

```
<item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopupMenu</item>
```

and try once...

Comment: What is the structure of values folder in your project

Comment: `values`, `values-land`, `values-sw600dp`, `values-v14`

Comment: Ok, then you're <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopupMenu</item> is correct, in values-v14

Comment: You were right! I forgot to change the values in `values-v14/styles.xml`! THANK YOU! Can you change your answer to that (making sure to set styles in both folders) and I'll mark it correct.

Comment: Hmm, it's not working on tablet. If I change the background for everything, then the menu background also changes. Otherwise, it won't change the menu color! Any ideas?

Comment: You're having values-sw600dp, it is for tablet add even in that

Comment: I found the answer and it's a weird bug. You have to first set a base theme which has the action bar parent and then make your app's theme descend from that: `<style name="BaseAppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"></style>` and the app's theme: `<style name="AppTheme" parent="BaseAppTheme">...styles go in here...</style>` See more here: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/style-androids-overflow-menu-using-this-sanity-saving-workaround/